# Continuous Time Markov Process on infinite state space

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

When we have a countably infinite state space what can we use to define the dynamics of our process, and how can we use this to then give a definition of a process in an equilibrium distribution /and a reversible distribution.

Reference to reading help just fine.

p.s (what can we do if the state space is uncountable)

Comment: ...what's stopping you from doing the same thing that you did in the finite case?